# When i am trying to update the text of a field, the content changes in debug information but doesn't in reallity

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, settext

I am trying to update the text of a textview. But the problem is that it does update the text when i inspect the element with the debugger. But in reality the content of the textview stays the same.

Could someone take a look at it, please.

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.firstapp.ZoekVelg$PlaceholderFragment" 
    android:id="@+id/ZoekVelgLL">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="BekijkDetailPage"
        android:text="Bekijk details" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:text="gewoon tekst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

If i make the changes you suggested, i get a null pointer exception

the code is like this now:

```
public class ZoekVelg extends ActionBarActivity {

    String merk, model, uitvoering;

    TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoek_velg);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        merk = intent.getStringExtra("merk");
        model = intent.getStringExtra("model");
        uitvoering = intent.getStringExtra("uitvoering");

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText("even updaten");


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

And the logcat:

```
06-13 10:50:07.410: I/Adreno-EGL(30518): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
06-13 10:50:07.410: I/Adreno-EGL(30518): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
06-13 10:50:07.410: I/Adreno-EGL(30518): Build Date: 02/04/14 Tue
06-13 10:50:07.410: I/Adreno-EGL(30518): Local Branch: 
06-13 10:50:07.410: I/Adreno-EGL(30518): Remote Branch: 
06-13 10:50:07.410: I/Adreno-EGL(30518): Local Patches: 
06-13 10:50:07.410: I/Adreno-EGL(30518): Reconstruct Branch: 
06-13 10:50:15.819: I/Adreno-EGL(30591): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
06-13 10:50:15.819: I/Adreno-EGL(30591): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
06-13 10:50:15.819: I/Adreno-EGL(30591): Build Date: 02/04/14 Tue
06-13 10:50:15.819: I/Adreno-EGL(30591): Local Branch: 
06-13 10:50:15.819: I/Adreno-EGL(30591): Remote Branch: 
06-13 10:50:15.819: I/Adreno-EGL(30591): Local Patches: 
06-13 10:50:15.819: I/Adreno-EGL(30591): Reconstruct Branch: 
06-13 10:50:17.261: W/dalvikvm(30591): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416a1e18)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591): Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 30591
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.ZoekVelg}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at com.example.firstapp.ZoekVelg.onCreate(ZoekVelg.java:40)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
06-13 10:50:17.271: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: why are you calling ll.invalidate() ?

Comment: @Shivam Verma Sorry that i saw your comment so late, i did that because i taught thay i maybe should refresh the view to make it appear but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two instances of the layout:

- one is set in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoek_velg);` (inflate is done by the superclass)
- one in `View currView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_zoek_velg, null);` (you do the inflate without attaching it to anything)

as you do TextView lookup on the second layout you change a TextView that is never shown to the user explaining what you see in debugger.

To fix comment out the lines:

```
    // LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    // View currView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_zoek_velg, null);
```

and use:

```
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
```

which will do the lookup on the layout set by `setContentView(..)` call.

ps: yes the invalidate is completely unnecessary :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if i make those changes i get a null pointer exception. I was struggling with that yesterday. You can see my code and my logcat at my original post now. with the changes you suggested.

Comment: changing the layout params of the root view of a layout is quite a bit tedius in android as there is not getContentView call counterpart of setContentView. 

it is way better to change the layout parameters in xml (`android:layout_*` attributes)

Comment: Oke thank you i will do that from now on. But that doesn't solve the NullPointerException problem.

Comment: yes, you are setting `match_parent` for both width and height in xml and changing to `wrap_content` programmatically. i would keep xml only, check how it looks and maybe change in xml if not satisfied.

Comment: you also get layout params from linear layout and put them on text view, you can use `txt.getLayoutParams()` modify them and use `txt.setLayoutParams(..)` (cast to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` when needed) but it's way simplier to modify xml if those params are not dynamic.

Comment: i changed that now. But i still get the null pointer. Could you take a look at the code above, i updated it again.

Comment: LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) currView.findViewById(R.id.ZoekVelgLL);

is null becouse you can't get the root of the linear layout by using findViewById and you don't need it tough

Comment: Oke i removed that line also, now i just get the intent after the setContentView. and then i instanciate the textview and set the text that is all. But still the nullpointer

Comment: should be correct... if you are using eclipse try cleaning project and rebuilding, sometimes eclipse messes up resource ids but your code seems correct now unless you change layout or remove view somewhere else.

Comment: I cleaned it but i still get the nullpointer. As far as i know i do not remove the view someone else. But i land on this page because i clicked on a button on another page do i have to post that page to? Or does it have nothing to do with it?

Comment: should have nothing to do with it, try to check that the layout u use in java and you posted are correct (contents and location) and you have `@+id/txt` only in that layout

Comment: i checked my files and this is the only field with the id txt. And i posted the correct code, with the correct references.

Comment: can you try to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but sadly enough i get the same null pointer error.

Comment: i even tried to make a new project what automaticly generates a Hello World app. And included those two lines in the Oncreate: TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
  txt.setText("natuurlijk"); After that i runned the project but still got a null pointer in the new project. Could it be any setting in my eclipse?

Comment: reboot of the device or try with an emulator? honestly i can't figure out why an automatically generated hello world app would not work unless you are really loading the wrong layout

Comment: it works when i just created the new app then i can run it and everything works fine, but after adding those two lines it crashes. But i will try a reboot.

Comment: are you loading `R.layout.activity_zoek_velg` and do you have only one `activity_zoek_velg.xml` in your project?

Comment: Yes in my code i load R.layout.activity_zoek_velg and i have only one activity_zoek_velg.xml file. The thing is that if i delete the change textview code the layout i defined in the xml file shows up so that means it does actually get loaded if i am right. Or is that not right?

Comment: i solved it by another post. The onCreate() method was to early to change the data. I putted the code in the onCreateView() method and it worked. Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The view that is displayed on the screen is set when you call the `setContentView()` method. When you inflate a view, its just created and even though the `setText()` method works, you don't see anything because its done on the inflated view which you dont really see.

To modify views on the current screen you can directly call findViewById(R.id.ID) and then typecast it.

Here's a code that'll work :

```
public class ZoekVelg extends ActionBarActivity {

    String merk, model, uitvoering;

    TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoek_velg);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        merk = intent.getStringExtra("merk");
        model = intent.getStringExtra("model");
        uitvoering = intent.getStringExtra("uitvoering");

        //Find View and then typecast
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText("even updaten");

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried your code, but i get a nullPointerException. I Updated the code above and included my LogCat. So maybe you could take a look at my code?

Comment: can you tell me which line is this : ZoekVelg.java:40

Comment: I hope you have a TextView with the id txt in the layout file : activity_zoek_velg

Comment: i have it in fragment_zoek_velg, should it be activity?